# Property of quotient ideals in a number Field

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraic number field.

Let $I$ and $J$ be two fractional ideals of $\mathbb{K}$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}$ a positive integer.

Is it true that $I/qI $ isomorphic to $J/qJ$? If yes, what is the isomorphism?

If no, is there a condition on $q$ that make it True?

Comment: Isomorphic in what sense? As abelian groups? As $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}}$-modules?

Comment: Besides, it will certainly not be true in any reasonable sense if you take $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}$, $I=(0), J=(1)$

Comment: What happen If $\mathbb{K}$ is a  cyclotomic number field?, and the ideals are not trivials.

Comment: But you have still not specified what you mean by your question...

Comment: No condition depending only on $q$ seems to exist as both $I/qI$ and $J/qJ$ are annihilated by $q$. There must be conditions on $I$ and $J$ to have isomorphism in certain circumstances.

Comment: But i don't understand what is the meaning of having quotient of fractional ideal, instead of integral ideals?